# What are other options on Gnu Grub Boot Loader on dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot

I am dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 and on the OS selection screen there are the options of Ubuntu and Windows, but I can see a few more options, Advanced Options and Memory test or sometthing like that. I dont really know what they might be and I couldnt find anything on the web. Can anyone explain me what they are? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that "Advanced options" allows you to edit one the 2 command lines / enter a custom command line or start the grub shell. The memory test is a progrm which runs (in place of a full operating system) to check your RAM is all working and to benchmark its performance.